# Wildfly SSO Logout Not Working - Session is Still Valid

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I am running Wildfly and am having issues with the invalidating the session upon user logout. I have set up a custom database login module and that works, but the logout functionality does not. I have pasted the relevant standalone.xml, jboss-web.xml and my servlet logout code.

The issue is that the session does not get invalidated after logout. Using the same JSESSIONIDSSO cookie, the user can still access pages that require roles even after logging out. I have tested that the roles are working properly - prior to login, pages requiring roles are inaccessible. After login, they are accessible. After logout, they are still accessible.

Has anyone else experienced these issues or do you know what has been misconfigured on my end?

standalone.xml

```
<security-domain name="myname-form" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="com.myname.DatabaseModLoginModule" flag="sufficient">
            <module-option name="securityDomain" value="jsse-myname"/>
            <module-option name="verifier" value="com.myname.X509Verifier"/>
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/jdbc/myds"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="exec h_Get_UserRoles ?, 1"/>
            <module-option name="fieldToSearchMap" value="CN=TEST"/>
            <module-option name="logQuery" value="exec h_Log_login_Attempt ?,?"/>
            <module-option name="certLogDir" value="C:\tools\wildfly\standalone\log\failedcerts"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
  <security-domain flushOnSessionInvalidation="true">myname-form</security-domain>
  <valve>
    <class-name>org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn</class-name>
  </valve>
  <context-root>/myname-form</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

ServletLogout.java

```
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Expires", new java.util.Date().toString());

        if (request.getSession(false) != null) {
          request.getSession(false).invalidate();
        }
        if (request.getSession() != null) {
          request.getSession().invalidate();
        }

        request.logout();
        response.sendRedirect(request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the `invalidate()` is actually removing the `JSESSIONID`? Another possibility that I have seen is that there is an interference from JSF because you have to redirect from a protected page (where you log out) to an unprotected page (to display the "logged out" message). If you don't have a clean transition, JSF will reinstate the session that it knows about, subverting the logout process.

Comment: It does not seem to be removing it. Both the `JSESSIONID` and the `JSESSIONIDSSO` are still valid (they do not get removed from the client's cookies) when I access a protected page. I do have it redirecting to the login page which requires no roles, so I would think that is a clean transition.

Comment: This may not be the same case you are expirienced, but I had some issues with wildfly 8.0.0 and flushOnSessionInvalidation. When you invalidate a session wildfly does not clean role cache for the user that has been authenticated (this could be a caused of your problem), this is bug planned to be fixed in 9.0.0, in the mean time you can check this workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931637/wildfly-caches-roles-after-logout-in-a-web-application/23231267#23231267. I also read in one of wildfly forums that version 8.1 has fixed lots of SSO bugs.

Comment: I am using Wildfly 10 and experiencing the same issue, so if it was fixed in 9 is present again in 10

Answer (score 4):

I am using Wildfly-8.1 and I had also many issues with SSO. First of all, as previously stated, you will need to flush the cache manually when the session is destroyed:

```
@WebListener
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Resource(name = "java:jboss/jaas/app/authenticationMgr")
    private CacheableManager<?, Principal> authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {

        // Flushes credentials.
        Principal principal = (Principal) httpSessionEvent.getSession()
                .getAttribute("principal");
        if (principal != null) {
            authenticationManager.flushCache(principal);
        }
    }
}
```

Wildfly has switched default web container to Undertow, so valve cannot be used anymore. You can delete that part from your jboss-web.xml

To enable SSO you need to edit the standalone.xml and add the "single-sign-on" option in the undertow subsystem (SSO is configured per host):

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.1">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
            <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
            <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            <single-sign-on path="/"/>
        </host>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config/>
    </servlet-container>
    <handlers>
        <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
    </handlers>
    <filters>
        <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/8"/>
        <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```

But is still not enough, as I had to logout twice to be able to logout. After following and discussing on this forum: [Wildfly SSO, does it support session timeout and logout?](https://community.jboss.org/thread/242039) I had to patch the Undertow module with the fixes on this forum and install it in Wildfly-8.1

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it relates to [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3221) JIRA issue, which is not resolved yet in Wildfly 8, but only in 9.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I've updated from Wildfly8.1.0.Final to Wildfly8.2.0.Final and the problem has gone.