# Need sample jboss-web.xml for jboss-6.4.8 version

Tags: jboss

We have recently upgraded our application from JBoss 5 to JBoss 6.4.8 version.
In JBoss 5 version, We were using the jboss-web.xml which has following attributes defined

```
<security-domain flushOnSessionInvalidation="true"/>
<use-session-cookies>true</use-session-cookies>
```

The same jboss-web.xml is not working with jboss 6 version.I need the sample jboss-web.xml and also wants to know how we can set the above attributes in the jboss 6 version.Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `$JBOSS_HOME/docs/schema/` there should be all deployment descriptors available as xsd. And yes `flushOnSessionInvalidation` no longer is part of jboss-web.xml. But i think they fixed it with EAP Versions 7.0.8.CR1, 7.0.8.GA. Have a look at [JBEAP-11895](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-11895)

As for your problem have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931637/wildfly-caches-roles-after-logout-in-a-web-application).

In the comments section of [WFLY-3221](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3221) is also an example.